# How can I get the state from App.jsx after login?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-router

I'm pretty new to React, and I'm having an issue with State in my App.jsx.  My react-router code is in App.js, which after logging in the default page (HomePage) will load.  I want to read the state after login to render my Header page if there is a user loaded in state.  The issue I have is that the state in App.jsx is still null.

After login, my state shows that user is populated, but App.jsx is always null.  I've tried pulling "user" from both props, and state, and I've tried adding user to mapState.

Here is what I have in my App.jsx:

```
import React from "react";
import { Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import { history } from "../_helpers";
import { alertActions } from "../_actions";
import { PrivateRoute } from "../_components";
import { HomePage } from "../HomePage";
import { LoginPage } from "../LoginPage";
import { RegisterPage } from "../RegisterPage";
import Header from "../Header/Header";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    history.listen((location, action) => {
      // clear alert on location change
      this.props.clearAlerts();
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { alert } = this.props;
    var user = this.state;
    let header = null;
    if (user) {
      header = <Header />;
    }
    return (
      <div>
        {header}
        <div className="jumbotron">
          <div className="container">
            <div className="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
              {alert.message && (
                <div className={`alert ${alert.type}`}>{alert.message}</div>
              )}
              <Router history={history}>
                <div>
                  <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
                  <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
                  <Route path="/register" component={RegisterPage} />
                </div>
              </Router>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapState(state) {
  const { alert } = state;
  return { alert };
}

const actionCreators = {
  clearAlerts: alertActions.clear
};

const connectedApp = connect(
  mapState,
  actionCreators
)(App);
export { connectedApp as App };
```

Any help, or suggestions of a better way to do this, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialize the state fist.
You have 2 options to do that:

1. Within your constructor: call this.state = {...}
2. Outside: somewhere in your component call state = {...}

Both of these calls will initialize your state to the default state and after that, calls to this.state will be defined.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  So in my App.js constructor, I need to add this.state= { user: null }?

Comment: Ok, I added this.state={ user:null } to my constructor, but when I console.log(this.state.user) in the App.js render method, it's still null after login.

Comment: render() {
    const { alert, user } = this.props;
    let header = null;
    console.log(this.state.user);

Comment: You mix state and props. Do you want to store the user in the state or just pass it from redux? I recommend the second way. If you just apss it, you have to access the user with this.props.user.

Answer (score 0):

The state isn't initialized. Be careful with that. `var user = this.state` can be removed and then you can initialize the state. Also, add `user` to the `state` object and instead of `if (user)` use `if (this.state.user)`. Then you can call `state`. I think this might be what you need.